# JQM + phonegap: select-button's "dialog" page doesn't scroll anymore

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile

in my Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 app + Phonegap 3.6.3, I have a dialog page, opened by a select button, and, on iOS, I can't scroll to the bottom of the list (it scrolls fine on Android and desktop).

If I swipe my finger on the list, the list doesn't scroll. 
The list is populated dynamically.

HTML:

```
<select id="chosenpro" data-theme="b" data-native-menu="false" data-position-to="window">
</select>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#welcome-page', function(){    

   $.when(dbReadyDeferred).then(function() {
        initializeSelectButtons();  //function where the select options are populated dynamically
   });

...
});
```

Can you help please ?

Comment: Very weirdly, it seems that `#chosenpro-dialog { /*.ui-mobile .ui-page-active*/
 overflow-x:visible;
}` fixes this problem....I really don't know why...